# oracle subquery with multiple output

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, subquery

Here is my table [answer] and [student_answer]

```
create table answer(
varchar2(10) ques_id,
varchar2(10) ans,
primary key (ques_id)
);

create table student_answer(
varchar2(10) stud_id,
varchar2(10) quiz_id,
varchar2(10) ques_id,
varchar2(10) ans,
number(3) mark,
primary key (stud_id,quiz_id,ques_id)
);

UPDATE student_answer
SET mark = 1
WHERE * IN (select ques_id, stud_id, quiz_id from answer m
right outer join student_answer sa
on (sa.ques_id = m.ques_id and sa.ans=m.ans)
where m.ques_id is not null
order by sa.ques_id);
```

*i got confused here

how can i get multiple row output per subquery? so that i can update a table according to the result?

```
* every student have different id
* every quiz have different id
* every question have different id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `IN` you have to have only one column at the left and the possibilities for that column at the right.

But i think you can probably do your `UPDATE` just with an `EXISTS`. Try this:

```
UPDATE student_answer sa
SET mark = 1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM answer m
    WHERE sa.ques_id = m.ques_id
      AND sa.ans = m.ans
    );
```